# How to add custom query / queryset to Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm building a Django project and have a model called Animal. Something like:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField()
```

In the django admin interface I can easily see all **animals** which is awesome.

However I would like to add 2 additional views to the admin so that I can see all **animals** of a certain type:

For example if my Admin view could look like this:

```
Animals -> Shows all animals (default)
Animals (type = dog) -> Shows only dogs
Animals (type = cat) -> Shows only cats
```

Any advice or best practices on how to do this? Thanks. The queries themselves would be super simple

```
Animals.objects.filter(type='dog')
```

Comment: i think you could use ***django.contrib import admin*** and make a ***class animals(admin.ModelAdmin)*** at your admin.py but not sure if you can filter a model with a charfield it would need at least a boolean field to filter

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for the [`list_filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) config property.

```
class AnimalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('type', )
```